# IOS Swift Thread Abort Error when Appending image to an image array

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error when I try to append an image to my image array in IOS swift: Thread 1:signal SIGABRT

It occurs when I call the `loadImages()` function:

```
import UIKit

class ProtectedGallery: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView!
    var images = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadImages()
    }

    func loadImages()
    {
        images.append(UIImage(named: "image1")!)
        self.imageCollection.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)-> Int{
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ imageCollection: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = imageCollection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        let image = images[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.image = image;
        return cell
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is the case? I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: please show more code

Comment: I added more code

Comment: add image1 to project

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `UIImage(named: "image1")!` you load an image ,, added it to your resources ?

Comment: yea I did, its in my Assets.xcassets folder in the project

Comment: The app crashes because you reload the collection view inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: No it still crashes even when I comment that line out

Comment: And if you try: guard let image = UIImage(named: "image1") else { return } and then images.append(image) inside func loadImages() instead of force unwrapping the image, does it still crash?

Comment: Yes it still crashes

Comment: What are you commenting out?  Move the loadImage things out of viewDidLoad.

Comment: @ElTomato reloading the collection view in viewDidLoad() shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: You should use indexPath.item for collection views & indexPath.row for table views i.e. let image = images[indexPath.item]. Might not be the problem here but try it. It's also good to sometimes clean-build your project (Product > Clean) then re-run it.

Comment: I did that in my collection view function definition

Comment: You are using let image = images[indexPath.row] but should be indexPath.item.

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed a few things:

First, you never set the data source (or delegate) for your collection view. Do that:

```
class ProtectedGallery: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView! {
        didSet {
            imageCollection.dataSource = self
            imageCollection.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your data source method arguments are not named correctly. Change to this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // put your code here
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // put your code here
}
```

Comment: I linked the datasource and delegate outlets to its class file. I don't see old ones. Or maybe I'm looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: I meant this: @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UICollectionView! which is created when you drag from interface builder. If you only ever did that once then it should be ok, but if you dragged multiple times and created more than one outlet, it can cause crashes.

Comment: Only did it once I think, I only right clicked it on the interface builder and don't see multiple outlets.

Comment: OK, then this is not the problem. But you at least see 'imageCollection' there when you right click, correct?

Comment: Yes I do, and I have the dataSource and delegate outlets linked to the correct "scene".

Comment: I did find aa weak var imageView: UIImageView! variable that was unlinked in my UICollectionViewCell, but I fixed that and the program still crashes

Comment: OK, probably not an outlet issue then. I noticed a few other issues and edited my answer, if it's not that then I can't see the problem!